# How to convert LocationResult class in Android into Location class?

Tags: java, android

I want to convert LocationResult class object to Location class object. So that I can access all method from Location class.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if(LocationResult.hasResult(intent)){
        LocationResult currentLocation = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
        calculateDistanceTo(currentLocation);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: I am trying to get location when it changes and compare it with locations that are saved in SQLite Db within 100m radius.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult

You'll see that you cant convert `LocationResult` to `Location`, as `LocationResult` has a list of `Location`.

Apply `getLocations()` and loop through each `Location` to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found another way                          LocationResult location = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult.extractResult(intent);
            Location currentLocation=location.getLastLocation();

Comment: `getLastLocation` will give you the last location the device known, but don't forget to check for null, because it has a chance to be null too. And if you are using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location`, it is better if you implement native location from android too, because not every device has google play service, especially android devices that manufactured from Chinese

Comment: I am checking Location result with this method LocationResult.hasResult(intent); and then extracting the location. Still, it will give null for the last location?